# Knockout $root context is wrong in foreach binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, typescript

When I use a `foreach` data-bind it seems to break the `$root` context for knockout.

When this happens `this` refers to an element (`user`) that is a child to the viewmodel (`page`) and parent to the foreach elements (`requests`), when it ought to refer to the viewmodel (`page`).

I refer to `$root` outside of the foreach with no issue - it calls the right method in the correct context.

**HTML where it works:**

```
<div id="home-page-view" class="view" data-bind="if: status() == AppStatus.Home">
        <button data-bind="click: $root.switchState">Switch To Friend Requests</button>
</div>
```

**Typescript where it works:**

```
public switchState() {
        if (this.status() == AppStatus.Home) {
            this.status(AppStatus.FriendRequests); //this refers to viewmodel (page)
        } else {
            this.status(AppStatus.Home);
        }
    }
```

However, when in a foreach, the buttons bound like `data-bind="click: $root.acceptFriendRequest"` successfully call their methods, but `this` refers to `user`, not `page`.

**HTML where its broken:**

```
<div id="friend-requests-view" class="view" data-bind="if: status() == AppStatus.FriendRequests">
    <h1>Friend Requests</h1>
    <p>View your pending friend requests.</p>

    <div data-bind="with: user">
        <div data-bind="foreach: requests">
            <div>
                <h2 data-bind="text: firstName"></h2>
                <p data-bind="text: lastName"></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Accept" data-bind="click: $root.acceptFriendRequest" />
                <input type="button" value="Deny" data-bind="click: $root.rejectFriendRequest" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Typescript where its broken:**

```
public acceptFriendRequest(newFriend: UserModel) {
        this.respondToFriendRequest(true, newFriend);
}

public rejectFriendRequest(notFriend: UserModel) {
        this.respondToFriendRequest(false, notFriend);
}
```

Even in the HTML where its broken, 4 lines prior `status()` implicitly refers to the correct `$root`.

What is going on here that makes `this` refer to `page.user` instead of `page`? Given that in other contexts `this` refers to `page`, it seems that `$root` ought to always refer back to `page`.

**MCVE:**

**Page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="DTO/DTOs.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="home-page-view" class="view" data-bind="if: status() == AppStatus.Home">
        <button data-bind="click: $root.switchState">Switch To Friend Requests</button>
    </div>

    <div id="friend-requests-view" class="view" data-bind="if: status() == AppStatus.FriendRequests">
        <h1>Friend Requests</h1>
        <p>View your pending friend requests.</p>

        <div data-bind="with: user">
            <div data-bind="foreach: requests">
                <div>
                    <h2 data-bind="text: firstName"></h2>
                    <p data-bind="text: lastName"></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="button" value="Accept" data-bind="click: $root.acceptFriendRequest" />
                    <input type="button" value="Deny" data-bind="click: $root.rejectFriendRequest" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.ts**

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/knockout.mapping/knockout.mapping.d.ts" />


var page: App;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    page = new App();
    ko.applyBindings(page);
});


class App {

    public user: KnockoutObservable<UserModel>;
    public status: KnockoutObservable<AppStatus> = ko.observable(AppStatus.Home);

    constructor() {
        this.user = ko.observable(new UserModel());
        var us: User = {firstName: "Chip", lastName: "Dipson" };
        this.user(ko.mapping.fromJS(us));
        this.user().requests.push(new UserModel());
    }

   public switchState() {
        if (this.status() == AppStatus.Home) {
            this.status(AppStatus.FriendRequests);
        } else {
            this.status(AppStatus.Home);
        }
    }

    public acceptFriendRequest(newFriend: UserModel) {
        this.respondToFriendRequest(true, newFriend); //this is wrong
    }

    public rejectFriendRequest(notFriend: UserModel) {
        this.respondToFriendRequest(false, notFriend); //this is wrong
    }

    private respondToFriendRequest(accepted: boolean, requester: UserModel) {
      //do some ajax stuff
    }
}

enum AppStatus {
    Home, FriendRequests
}
```

**DTOs.ts**

```
class User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    requests: User[];
}

class UserModel {
    firstName: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("");
    lastName: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("");

    requests: KnockoutObservableArray<UserModel> = ko.observableArray<UserModel>(null);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `click` binding takes a function, not a snippet of code. That means that $root isn't providing execution context, it is only helping you to locate the function. If you want the execution context to be set, you will need to `bind` it:

```
<input type="button" value="Accept" data-bind="click: $root.acceptFriendRequest.bind($root)" />
```

Comment: This was it. Thanks!